# JQUERY, TEXT, appending an LI to a list with a SPAN wrapped?

Tags: jquery

here is my current line of code:

```
$("<li>").text($(this).text()).appendTo("#theList");
```

Which results in

```
<ul id="theList">
<li>blah</li>
<li>blah</li>
</ul>
```

How can I update that code above to result in:

```
<ul id="theList">
<li><span>blah</span></li>
<li><span>blah</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this. I know from your previous question you are getting this data from a span in which case you can [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) it:

```
$("span.findme").clone().appendTo("#theList");
```

You might want to remove the class:

```
$("span.findme").clone().removeClass("findme").appendTo("#theList");
```

Alternatively using `each()`:

```
$("span.findme").each(function() {
  var span = $("<span>").text($(this).text());
  $("<li>").append(span).appendTo("#theList");
});
```

Comment: thxs but I'm not seeing how that would work with the previous? 
$("<li>").text($(this).text()).appendTo("#theList")

Comment: @nobosh: see the updated version. It works instead of the `each()` loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can probably use wrap:

```
$("<li>").text($(this).text()).wrap("<span></span>").appendTo("#theList");
```